# How to create and add video overlays like this?

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I saw this overlay and want to reproduce it, but wonder how to do this:

[image: image overlay]

It was slightly animated / synchronized with the video.

- How do I reproduce this on my own videos?
- Which software is ideally suited for this task?

*I currently use Adobe Premiere.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool doesn't matter in this case.

For some kind of artistic or individual approach I'd suggest use a [light table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_table) or [graphics tablet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_tablet). Draw the shapes 20-50 times by hand to get some nice variation and place all the drawings on top of each other like [classic/traditional animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_animation) does in the old days.

Otherwise you can either use:

- Any kind of *pixel* or vector based [graphics package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_software) (Photoshop, Gimp, Affinity Designer etc.) together with Premiere or *After Effects for additional tracking capabilities*
- A [2D Animation package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_2D_animation_software) which allows to draw directly on the plates
- Or even Blender's [grease pencil feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fqjv_CKgLlI)  along with its tracking capabilities

Comment: Beginner's tutorial on [How to Scribble Over a Video in Blender?](https://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-scribble-over-a-video-in-blender--cms-25228)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably find it easiest to use a motion graphics application. There are many. Since you're using Premiere, you might find [Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) familiar. If you're on a Mac, you might also like [Apple's Motion](http://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/motion/). Both apps allow you to create shapes, use text, and animate it. The above type of graphics should be fairly easy to produce in either app.